# How to handle recursive relations in data models in TypeORM?

Tags: mysql, typeorm

**moderators**

| id | email | password | settingsId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

**moderator_settings**

| id | moderatorId | language |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

I have two tables, **moderators**, and **moderator_settings**, the relationship is described in the entity as bellow:

```
@Entity('moderators')
export class Moderator extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int', name: 'id' })
  id: string | number

  @Column({ name: 'email', type: 'varchar', length: 100 })
  email: string

  @Column({ name: 'password', type: 'varchar', length: 100 })
  password: string

  @Column({ name: 'settingsId', type: 'int' })
  settingsId: string

  @OneToOne(()=> ModeratorSettings)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'settingsId' })
  settings: ModeratorSettings

}


@Entity('moderator_settings')
export class ModeratorSettings extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int', name: 'id' })
  id: string | number

  @Column({ name: 'language', type: 'varchar', length: 100 })
  language: string

  @Column({ name: 'moderatorId', type: 'int' })
  moderatorId: string

  @OneToOne(()=> Moderator)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'moderatorId' })
  moderator: Moderator

}
```

In order to create a moderator, I have to have a moderator setting id, and in order to create a moderator setting row, I need to have a moderator Id.

So how I can create any of the two, when I don't have the other?

I feel like this is a closed loop.

I remember in the days of PHP, we used to have a method in mysqli that we used to generate an ID ourselves.

The method would generate an id from the database and reserve it, so that we can use it in our code.

My id columns are auto increment, so the ids are 1, 2, 3, 4 in sequence.